# How to select a specific line/row from PHPmyadmin. Not by LİMİT or ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a Java program that can take from a MySQL database a row.

I Select it directly, not by LIMIT or ORDER BY because it is not useful for me because when I select the first row I don't want it to be printed again the showing the seceond one like in LIMIT.

[image]

Is it possible to select a specific row not ? I would appreciate how can help me

```js
String ff1 = name.getText();
Connection con = myConnection.getconnection();

try {
  PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT `id`,`dafat`, `sinif`, `adet`, `price`, `type`, `total` FROM " + ff1 + " LIMIT 1");
  ResultSet resultset = ps.executeQuery();
  while (resultset.next()) {
    System.out.println(resultset.getString("id"));
    System.out.println(resultset.getString("sinif"));
    System.out.println(resultset.getString("adet"));
    System.out.println(resultset.getString("price"));
    System.out.println(resultset.getString("type"));
    System.out.println(resultset.getString("total"));
  }
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Comment: You need a `WHERE` clause. See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With selection key**

If you have a "selection key" you can just use it to retrieve the row you want. For example:

```
SELECT `id`,`dafat`, `sinif`, `adet`, `price`, `type`, `total` 
FROM t
WHERE `id` = 5
```

**Without selection key**

Now, if you don't have a selection key you need to define some *row ordering criteria* to decide which row is the first one, the second one, etc.

This is because in a table rows do not have inherent row ordering. As simple as that. The fact that your tool retrieves the rows in one order is not assured if you don't specify an ordering criteria. In the absence of an ordering criteria, you get them as you see them today, but tomorrow they could be presented differently.

Now, if we assume the row ordering is by the `id` column, then you can select the "nth" row by skipping `n - 1` rows.

For example, if you want to select the 5th row, you can skip the first 4 rows using `OFFSET 4`, as in:

```
SELECT `id`,`dafat`, `sinif`, `adet`, `price`, `type`, `total` 
FROM t
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1 -- return 1 row at most
OFFSET 4 -- skip the first 4 rows
```

Comment: i would very like they to add this feature. When you search for the row with a given id number by search input box :( . Too much come across that